# Problema ao passar parametros pela url usando o angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

Galera eu tenho um template aqui que usa o angularJS e o sistema de rotas dele está da seguinte forma

```js
.state('app.produto', {
                  url: '/produto',
                  templateUrl: 'tpl/detProdutos.php',
                  // use resolve to load other dependences
                  resolve: {
                      deps: ['uiLoad',
                        function( uiLoad ){
                          return uiLoad.load( ['js/app/produto-calc.js',
                                               JQ_CONFIG.moment] );
                      }]
                  }
              })
```

e no html ele está assim:

`<a ui-sref="app.produto" class="pull-left thumb-md avatar b-3x m-r">`

e eu precisava passar pela URL o ID do produto mas não sei como faço isso no angular... alguem tem ideia de como faço isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve, primeiramente, declarar que a url espera um parâmetro, deste modo:

```
url: '/produto:idProduto', //ou /produto/:idProduto
```

Depois você passa esse parâmetro pelo link como um objeto, assim:

```
ui-sref="app.produto({idProduto: $scope.idProduto})" //o "idProduto" definido aqui deve ser sempre igual ao definido no `state`
```

Lembrando que este é apenas um modo de utilizar os parâmetros do uiRouter, [aqui você pode ler mais](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/url-routing) a respeito disso.

Comment: E nesse exemplo seu ai o numero do ID vai aonde?

Comment: @AlfredoLima ali onde diz $scope.idProduto, basta substituiir pela sua referencia do id do produto

Comment: ah valeu entendi agora, muito obrigado...